# Lag in fetching serial data from Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, python

I am working on a project based on **Arduino** and **python3.6**,two HC-SR04 sense the distance of palms and process the data using Arduino and send it through serial port to python3.6 ,python3.6 with the help of **pyserial** ,**pyautogui** based on data from arduino controls a game named **supertuxcart**,a racing game,basically the thought behind this is  controlling game with palms instead of keyboard or mouse .But the problem am facing is Arduino takes the distance measurement data from two HC-SR04(one for each hand) ultrasonic sensors, processes according and sends processed data through serial port to python3.6 ,there while running the my python script i open the game to check if its working ,it works, but there is lag in data received from arduino thus turn the game messy.

here is **arduino** code am using with **NewPing** library

```
#include <NewPing.h>
int trig1=9;
int echo1=6;
int trig2=7;
int echo2=5;
int R;
int L;
NewPing right(9,6,100);
NewPing left(7,5,100);
void setup() {

  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,INPUT);
  pinMode(5,INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Serial.println("hi,am arduino");
  R=right.ping_cm();
  L=left.ping_cm();
  //Serial.println(R);
  //Serial.println(L);
  delay(0000);
 if (R==0 && L==0){
    Serial.println('0');
  }
  else if(R<L&&L-R>5){
    Serial.println('1');
  }
  else if(R>L&&R-L>5){
    Serial.println('2');

delay(3000);

  }

}
```

Here is **python3.6** code am using

```
import serial
import pyautogui
import time

Arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
time.sleep(0)
print(Arduino.readline())
pyautogui.keyDown('up')
while 1:
    Data = Arduino.readline()
    print(Arduino.readline())

    if Data == b'0\r\n':
        pyautogui.keyUp('up')
        pyautogui.keyUp('right')
        pyautogui.keyUp('left')
        break
    elif Data == b'1\r\n':
        pyautogui.keyUp('left')
        pyautogui.keyDown('right')
    elif Data == b'2\r\n':
        pyautogui.keyUp('right')
        pyautogui.keyDown('left')
```

Comment: You could try using a higher baudrate, instead of just 9600.

Comment: Possible explanation for the lag. Since serial data is being buffered; if you send data faster, than the serial connection can handle, you'd get lag. As the latest data has to wait in line to be send. Using a tiny delay, or better `Serial.flush()`, or Majenko's #3 suggestion would eliminate the lag caused by buffering.

Comment: NewPing right(9,6,100);
NewPing left(7,5,100); Is the 100 the timeout for no return? Can you make that shorter?

Comment: its maximum distance ,100cm

Comment: Don't edit the question and invalidate an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things jump out at me:

1. You only need to run `Serial.begin(9600)` once in `setup()` - never in `loop()` like that.
2. Your `delay(3000)` will be causing a 3 second delay when `R>L&&R-L>5`.
3. You don't need to constantly send the data over and over again. You just need to send it once and once only when the state changes.

At the moment you're sending something like:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

when all you really need to do is send `01020`. Remember what the state is and only send anything when that state changes from one iteration to the next. And never ever use `delay()`.

Comment: The code is using Serial.println, so it's more like `0\r\n0\r\n1\r\n1\r\n`. So three bytes, for every byte of actual data.

Comment: Yeah, but still it's overkill.  And I didn't want to make my post 6 miles long to illustrate a point...